# Handling Events in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So this is my first MVVM application. I have a "shell" view model named MainWindowViewModel for the main window that basically splits the view into two pages: MainWindowRibbon and MainWindowFrame. The MainWindowViewModel stores both pages as properties, which I plan to use databinding to update in the UI. Here is some of the code for reference:

MainWindowView xaml~

```
<Grid>
    <Frame Content="{Binding MainWindowRibbon}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Frame Content="{Binding MainWindowFrame}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

MainWindowView code behind~

```
    public partial class MainWindowView : Window
{
    public MainWindowView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
        DataContext = mainWindowViewModel;
    }
    public MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel;
}
```

MainWindowViewModel code~

```
        public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        //MainWindowRibbon and MainWindowFrame are declared as public Page properties
        MainWindowRibbon = new MainWindowRibbonView();
        MainWindowFrame = new WelcomePageView();
    }
```

The MainWindowRibbonView, like the MainWindowView, instantiates the MainWindowRibbonViewModel.

My trouble comes when I wish to use an event within the MainWindowRibbonViewModel that will call for the MainWindowViewModel to reassign the MainWindowFrame page. I do not know how to connect the button command of the navigation bar I have created in the MainWindowRibbonView to cause an event or change in the MainWindowViewModel.

I do not know if the way I have organized this is ideal. Please let me know if I need to revise.

If somebody could help me determine the best approach, or even just a functioning one, I would be very grateful.

P.S.
Sorry if the naming conventions aren't the greatest.

Edit:
Lesson learned: listen to Joe.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what the `Frame` is.  It's a `ContentControl`.  You do not set its `Content` to some type of UI element.  Instead you set it to hold an instance of some view-model (e.g. `PersonViewModel`).   The UI for it comes in XAML;  You lay out a default `DataTemplate` for that view-model class-type.   The `DataTemplate` has UI controls that bind to that view-model's properties. So that whenever the `Content` property is set to an object of that type, defined in the `DataTemplate`, then it will show the UI you've laid out in the  `DataTemplate`, property bound.

Comment: You might want to read this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it depends on what kind of button you are using in your navigation bar.  is it a `RadioButton`?  A `RibbonToggleButton`?  Is it a regular button binding to an `ICommand`?

Since you called your Navigation Bar a "Ribbon", let us suppose it is a `RibbonToggleButton` (which is still basically a CheckBox).  If it is checked, you show some view-model your "page 1".   If it is not checked, you should another view-model representing your "page 2"

Let us also suppose your view's ribbon is up top.  So you have two rows:  the Ribbon row and the content row.

I might rewrite your MainWindow to look like this, (note the `IsChecked` property to some boolean property in your view-model like so:)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>  <!-- The "Ribbon" -->
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>     <!-- The page content -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ToggleButton Content="Show Page 1" IsChecked="{Binding ShowPage1}"/>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row=1>
        <Frame Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And I might write your view-model like this:  (Note that I assume it implements INotifyPropertyChanged and I call a function `RaisePropertyChanged` that I do not show.

```
public class Page1ViewModel {}  // Fill this out with Page 1 properties
public class Page2ViewModel {}  // Fill this out with Page 2 properties

// MainWindowViewModel.  Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.  Implementation
// is not shown here.

public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Page1ViewModel = new Page1ViewModel();
    private Page2ViewModel = new Page2ViewModel();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _currentViewModel = Page1ViewModel;
        ShowPage1 = true;
    }

    private object _currentViewModel;

    // The current contents of the main frame.

    public object CurrentViewModel 
    { 
        get => _currentViewModel;
        set
        {
            if (value == _currentViewModel)
                return;

            _currentViewModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
    }

    // Should CurrentViewModel be page 1 or page 2?

    public bool ShowPage1 
    { 
        get => return _currentViewModel == Page1ViewModel;
        set
        {
            if (value == ShowPage1)
                return;

            CurrentViewModel = value ? Page1ViewModel : Page2ViewModel;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I am not showing you any of the properties of `Page1VieModel` or `Page2ViewModel` nor have I shown you the implicit `DataTemplate`s I assume you will write for them.

Also I am assuming that your navigation bar (and `MainWindowView` in general) have a `DataContext` that is already set to the `MainWindowViewModel`

The implemention with a command button or a `RadioButton` would be quite different.

Comment: Thank you Joe for your thorough response. After reviewing, I decided to incorporate the "MainWindowRibbon" (which does not involve ribbon toggle buttons, which I may investigate now, but it was just unfortunate naming. I used regular buttons using ICommand in an ItemsControl template.) into the mainwindow. I suppose my greatest question now is how does the Content property access a xaml, with code behind, with a viewmodel class? i.e. what is the object type of the viewmodel? Sorry if I'm being a noob right now.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I create a datatemplate in the main xaml for each page? Sorry, I have most of the dots connected but not all

Comment: In answer to your second question, yes, I am suggesting you create a `DataTemplate` for each page.  The `DataTemplate` really *is* the page, at least in UI terms.  Meanwhile, the `Content` of each page is some sort of view-model object that, by itself, has no UI (e.g. some view-model class in your project).  This allows you to later add in new page types if you wish without changing the mechanism.  Basically you have to stop thinking of "content" in terms of UI/Controls and start thinking of it in terms of view-models.  DataTemplating translates the latter into the former.

Comment: WPF is meant to work this way, with templating.  You mentioned you used an `ItemsControl`, right?  Well that control works the same way except, instead of managing one `ContentControl` it manages many.  You bind an `ItemsControl` to a list of view-models somewhere stored in your code.  It shows you a list of `ContentControls`, one for each item in your list.  It has an `ItemTemplate` property that is the `DataTemplate` used to convert each list item into a UI.  So again, the items in your list are not UI controls, they're view-models.

Comment: Fantastic thank you so much, man. Now for the fun part of reworking the whole project :) Shouldn't be too bad though. Thanks again.